# Apache Apex CLI launch error - protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, apache-apex

I'm trying to launch an apa file from the Apache Apex CLI (version 3.4) on a Hadoop cluster running 2.7.4-SNAPSHOT and Protobuf v2.6.1 and I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList.getUnmodifiableView()Lcom/google/protobuf/LazyStringList;
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnServiceProtos$GetApplicationsRequestProto$Builder.buildPartial(YarnServiceProtos.java:17322)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnServiceProtos$GetApplicationsRequestProto$Builder.build(YarnServiceProtos.java:17310)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.protocolrecords.impl.pb.GetApplicationsRequestPBImpl.mergeLocalToProto(GetApplicationsRequestPBImpl.java:79)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.protocolrecords.impl.pb.GetApplicationsRequestPBImpl.getProto(GetApplicationsRequestPBImpl.java:69)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getApplications(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:249)

Any ideas what is wrong or how I can debug this?    Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the application package does not contain hadoop-xxx artifacts (those are provided by the cluster) or conflicting versions of transitive dependencies of those. If applicable you can use

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to find out how they get included (and exclude them).